# Partial Sandbox: Copy the records that belong to certain record types of a standard object

Tags: sandbox, record-type, sandbox-refresh

Is there a way to copy just the records that belong to certain record types of a standard object? In my case the standard object would be Account.

I cannot find anything in the documentation.

Comment: It looks like `Sandbox Templates` lack that level of granularity.

Comment: @AdrianLarson Thanks, that's a little unfortunate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think there is any way to copy the Account object records in partial sandbox. Try to create a report of records that belong to the record type you want with list of sfdc id's and try to insert them into your partial sandbox. try to see if this works.